# How to chain DB relationships in Laravel (multiple has_many?)

Tags: php, mysql, activerecord, laravel, eloquent

I'm using Laravel, which is awesome, but I'm stuck on an issue with the database.

Let's say we have three tables, like so:

**TABLE 1: pages**

```
id    |   route   |  title
```

**TABLE 2: elements**

```
id    |   page_id   |  type
```

**TABLE 3: content**

```
id    |   element_id   |  data
```

I'd like to do a single selection for the page that will in turn select all of the elements with that page id, and for each of the elements it should select all of the content rows with the element id.

I want to have a static **load_by_route($route)** function in the Page model that, when called, will use the route to load and return the page info as well as the elements and content as described above. Ideally it would return a single object/array with all of this info.

Basically, I'm not sure how to chain the has_many() calls together so that I get the two-level relationship.

Comment: just keep joining all the tables.  have you attempted any SQL?

Comment: I'm writing it all using Laravel's Eloquent: http://laravel.com/docs/database/eloquent, rather than straight SQL.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Look into eager loading. This should do what you want.

```
class Page extends Eloquent {

    public function elements()
    {
        return $this->has_many( 'Element' );
    }

}

class Element extends Eloquent {

    public function contents()
    {
        return $this->has_many( 'Content' );
    }

}

class Content extends Eloquent {}

$page = Page::with( array( 'elements', 'elements.contents' ) )->first();
```

https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading

Comment: Awesome, thanks! I hadn't realized that that was the term I needed to look for--I'd been just reading all of the sections on relationships. Thanks!

Comment: Just to note here, this approach does not chain relationships together at all. It does eager loading of the child model records, but that is still done through a series of separate queries when the `Page` is fetched.

Comment: Eager loading with multiple relationships (from [5.3 docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading)) - $books = App\Book::with('author', 'publisher')->get();

Answer (score 0):

Collin James answer gives you one object with all the data. I came here because I just wanted to iterate over all `contents` that belong to a page. Here is how you get such a collection:

```
  $page = Page::with('elements.contents.element')->has('elements.contents');

  $contents = [];
  foreach ($page->elements as $element) {
    $contents = $element->contents->merge($temp);
  }
```

The `with` makes sure that you use [eager loading](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) and the `has` [makes sure that we only iterate over elements with content](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-existence).

From each content element you can get the element info from the `belongsTo` relationship that we also received with eager loading:

```
class Content extends Eloquent 
{

 public function element()
 {
    returh $this->belongsTo('\App\Page');
 }

}
```